# Exim installed, can send mail but not receive any

Tags: debian, email, exim

I am trying to set up the mail service on my server. I installed exim4 and configured it.
I can send emails to any email address, send one from a user to another but not receive any.

When I try to send one from gmail I get a mail from gmail daemon with the subject: `Delivery Status Notification (Failure)` stating `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table`

The user exists for sure because I replied to the mail I first sent from my server.

My MX lookup:

```
example.org mail is handled by 10 mx2.example.org
example.org mail is handled by 10 mx1.example.org
```

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't `relay recipient table` as denoted above. In fact, you have to configure so-called `local_domains` that belongs to your MTA and `localparts` aka users that have mailboxes within your `local_domains`.

Comment: I have a `MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS=@:localhost:l3uz.it` in my configuration which is used for the local_domains. But I can't seem to find how to configure localparts in exim, counld not find it in their documentation. Any help on this?

Comment: I tried this manually just now and got "Recipient address rejected: Greylisted, see http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/help/l3uz.it.html" when sending to someone@l3uz.it, but that could just be me.

Comment: Well I still get the same result when I try to send an email

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem after finding out that my MX servers were hosted by my DNS provider and that it kept the mail for itself.

Sorry for bothering for nothing! :D